# Плагин gulp-sass не устанавливается

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

**Ребята, подскажите как решить эту проблему? Не могу установить плагин gulp-sass **

```
npm install node-sass gulp-sass --save-dev

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\AMD_RYZEN_5\\Desktop\\gulp-config\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\AMD_RYZEN_5\\Desktop\\gulp-config\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.1.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\AMD_RYZEN_5\\Desktop\\gulp-config\\node_modules\\node\\bin\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\AMD_RYZEN_5\\Desktop\\gulp-config\\node_modules\\gulp-sass\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\Desktop\gulp-config\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AMD_RYZEN_5\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-09T13_07_49_047Z-debug.log
```

Comment: судя по ошибке у вас не уставновлен `python`

Comment: пакет node-sass устаревший, вместо него [Dart sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/master/README.md#from-npm)